# How did Bohr guess the quantization rule?

Tags: physics, quantum-mechanics, bohr

We all know Bohr's quantization rule as $L = \frac{nh}{2\pi}$. How did Bohr derive this?

If it is a guess, what is the reason behind choosing $\frac{h}{2\pi}$ and not some other constant? Why did he equate it with angular momentum and not anything else?

Comment: Action, actually. See [this](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/4994/was-there-any-atomic-models-that-came-between-bohrs-and-the-actual-beginning).

Comment: Constant $h$ was earlier introduced by Planck. It has dimension (units) same as angular momentum. So the natural idea to explain discrete spectrum was to set $L=cnh$, where $c$ is a dimensionless constant. Comparing his theory with the observed spectral lines of hydrogen (Balmer's series) one can conclude that $c=1/2\pi$.

Comment: And how tough it should have been to calculate the values... Great guys of the Past.